# This site can’t be reached http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello using Flask as web framework

Tags: python, web, flask, server

I am trying to run a simple "hello world" code using flask version 1.1.1 and python 3.7. the server is running but the web page is not loading. Can anyone please help???

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/hello')
def hello_world():
    return "Hello world"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1',port=8000, debug=True)
```

Output is as below
[image]
But the web page(http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello) displays "This site can’t be reached"

Comment: the port in the title is 8080 and in the questions is 8000. server is running on 8000. Are you sure it's not just a typo - wrong port?

Comment: @buran , Sorry for wrong info, it was a type mistake. I tried using different port like 8000,8080,5000. finally worked for 7999 port number. Thank you for your immediate response

Answer (score -1, accepted):

make host =0.0.0.0 in app.run() and whatever port you will give it will work and if you will not give port in by default it will take 5000

Answer (score 1):

I encountered same problem when I change my default port from 5000 to 6000 with app.run(debug=True, host='127.0.0.1', port=6000). Which is the time I got `this site can't be reached` with unsafe port error from Chrome.

However, when I just tried with port 5001, 6868, 7999. All of them worked. Therefore, I guess if a port didn't work, it might be simply that some hidden system functions are already using it as a listening port, and all you gotta do is by changing and testing if any other port number could work

Answer (score 0):

I tried using different port like 8000,8080,5000. finally worked for 7999 port number. The appropriate solution for this kind of problem is to experiment with different port numbers